# How to increment a Hex number

Tags: swift, formatting, hex

I am looking for help to increment a hexadecimal by 1.  An example of this might be "000001" or "AD02D3" and increment to "000002" or "AD02D4".  I can't figure out how to do this in Swift.  If I convert to an Int:
    var num2 = Int(str, radix: 16)
I loose all the preceding zeros and there are difficulties converting back.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ??? I loose all the preceding zeros and there are difficulties converting back ??? please, show us at least some fragment of your code, how you tried to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the string length in a variable
Convert to an integer `Int(str, radix: 16)`
Add 1 to the integer
Use a format string with the saved length and specifying leading "0"s
Create the new string for the `format` function

```
let str = "00000A"

let len = str.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let num2 = Int(str, radix: 16)! + 1
let newStr = NSString(format: "%0\(len)X", num2) as String

print("newStr: \(newStr)")  // newStr: 00000B
```

Comment: Perfect Zaph!  This is great.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

func inc(s: String)->String? {
    if let i = Int(s,radix: 16)?.successor() {
        return String(format: "%0\(s.characters.count)X", arguments: [i])
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

let arr0 = ["01","0000FE00","FFFFFF"]
let arr1 = arr0.flatMap{ inc($0) }

print(arr1) // ["02", "0000FE01", "1000000"]
```